# Can we reference a class from inside a interface?

Tags: java

Can we reference a class from our interface? Whenever i run the code it says package controller does not exist. If gives the error as controller.Tool package does not exist

```
import controller.Tool;
public interface IRemoteDraw extends Remote {

    public void Draw(Tool tool) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: Is `controller.Tool` in your buildpath?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn typo in the copy paste, there is a  `;` in the code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes the controller is in the buildpath

Comment: The error is not 'inside' the interface - the import statement occurs before the interface declaration.  It's just the package name that is wrong.

Comment: "Whenever i run the code" and "the controller is in the buildpath" - does that mean that compilation or at least the IDE don't complain about that package but when trying to run the application you get that error? If so then make sure that class is on the _classpath_ (at runtime) and not just the _build_ path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can reference a class from inside the interface. Your classpath is configured such that there is no package named 'controller' in the root. Line 1 (the import statement) thus is an error, and the rest is irrelevant.

You haven't provided any further detail; this makes it impossible to guess as to why your classpath is misconfigured.